# Meteor : how to submit to Apple Store?

Tags: ios, meteor

I don't know anything about Apple store. 
Coming from Meteor I could pretty easily upload my app to android store.

Ios seems hundred of time more complex. Is there a good documentation on the steps to follow to upload a meteor app to App Store with XCode ?

I am fighting with The ios appstore, not meteor, I have to say.

EDIT :

Here is a note on what I did : http://www.slideshare.net/secret/peqPu2zUbRqsz0

I am lost in all the pages of Itunes documentations available. I am looking for a tutorial.

Comment: The instructions here https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-ios are pretty straight-forward as far as the meteor process goes. Can you provide more information on what you have done so far? Have you created the Xcode project?  Have you archived the project?  Have you set things up on iTunesConnect.

Comment: the meteor part is butter and honey. The App Store part is hell.

Comment: Again, please provide more details. Have you created your signing certificate on the developer portal and installed it in Xcode?  Created an app profile on the developer portal (XCode can do this for you) The process has a few steps but is a lot more automated than it used to be.

Comment: I updated my question with a slide share on all the stuff I have been digging on about creating a ios app. I am lost and need a good tutorial :-s

Comment: Here are Apple's instructions: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html  A specific error message or problem statement would help.